# Scroll bar not showing in Safari 5.1.3 (7534.53.10)

Tags: safari, scrollbar

I have a page setup with a scroll bar that is set with a css overflow function but the scroll bar will not showing in Safari  5.1.3? It shows in different versions of IE/FF and even older versions of Safari (5.0.5).

I have tried every combination of "overflow" I know of, "overflow:scroll;", "overflow:auto;", "overflow-x:scroll;" "overflow-y:scroll;" etc. but none work. I have even tried setting in-line styling of css but can't get it to show.

The html (this is not the complete html, there are a lot more images in the div, I just didn't want to put too much html in the post. I have 25 images in each div, so 5 "ul"s with 5 images in each "ul"):

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="images/rings/large/ring01_L.jpg"><img src="images/rings/thumbnails/ring01.jpg" width="75" height="75" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/rings/large/ring02_L.jpg"><img src="images/rings/thumbnails/ring02.jpg" width="75" height="75" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/rings/large/ring03_L.jpg"><img src="images/rings/thumbnails/ring03.jpg" width="75" height="75" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/rings/large/ring04_L.jpg"><img src="images/rings/thumbnails/ring04.jpg" width="75" height="75" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/rings/large/ring05_L.jpg"><img src="images/rings/thumbnails/ring05.jpg" width="75" height="75" border="0" /></a></li>
    </ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#thumbs1 {
    height: 450px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 120px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Here is a link to my sample page I have been testing with - [page](http://www.test25.net/gems/jQueryUI/myDesign/standarg-thumbnail-scroll-page.html) Each div has a different option set for overflow, but still none work in Safari 5.1.3.

Any pointers?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the user that was seeing this issue was using a track-pad with here MAC, when she unplugs the track-pad she can see the scroll bar!

So it seems that the screen acts like an iPhone when the track-pad is plugged in as on an iPhone you do not get the scroll bar either. If using a track-pad you have to use two fingers and drag the thumbs to scroll, like on an iPhone.

Hope this will help others avoide spending the same amount of time I spent on this!

Answer (score 0):

The height is bigger than the height of the 5 images together, reduce the height in CSS and try again ;)

Comment: I am not looking for a vertical scroll, this is why I set a larger height. I just want a horizontal scroll.

Comment: Try using a fixed width, percentage are disparating in CSS3... It would fix your problem.

Comment: I'll give that a try so, but won't be able to check until tomorrow, not near this mac now. Will post back results. Cheers...

Comment: No luck on this I'm afraid, still no scroll bar. I have specified a width of 260px which is less than the width of the 5 images and formatted four different divs with different overflow settings on my sample page. Can anyone test this for me on a different mac running Safari 5.1.3, just so I know if it is just this mac or the browser version? Thanks...

Comment: Cheers @Frederick, it also works on IE8 & 9 on Windows, and also FF on Windowsn and Mac, just seems to be Safari 5.1.3! I might have to just look into another way of navigating these images, maybe with js. Tks...

Comment: I think it's because the Safari 5.1.3 support only HTML5 and just a little bit HTML4 and XHTML1... Try searching a HTML5 method ;)